# preventing newline after wxpython TextCtrl.WriteText()

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, textctrl

I have a shell-like console for my app, which prompts with ">>>" after every command. The problem is every time I have my shell WriteText(">>> "), it also appends a new line. The user can backspace up to the correct line, but this just looks terrible. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is a wxpython TextCtrl.WriteText() operation

Comment: (Something somewhere is adding a newline... find out where it is :p)

Comment: Tried it. Yes really awful. Got no solution for it

Comment: add some minimal code demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you are declaring your `TextCtrl` to be of style `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` and then binding the `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` event - only because I ran into the same problem when I tried that.

My first instinct was to write a method to process `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` that would then use the `TextCtrl:Remove()` method. This method only seems to remove visible characters, unfortunately. My next thought was to use the `EmulateKeyPress()` method along with backspace (`WKX_BACK`) to erase the newline character. This might be doable though I couldn't come up with a good way to spoof a `wx.KeyEvent` (can't just use `event.m_keyCode` since `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` sends a `CommandEvent`, and not a `KeyEvent`) so I gave up on that approach... err, I mean this solution is left as an exercise to the reader.

`wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` being a `CommandEvent` finally led to a third angle which did work. Instead of binding `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER`, I bound `wx.EVT_CHAR` and put in logic with special processing for the `Return` key (ASCII key code 13). I then planned to implement the `EmulateKeyPress()` bit I talked about earlier but when I removed  `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` from the TextCtrl style, I discovered that the `\n` was no longer being surreptitiously added. Code follows:

```
import wx

class TestRun(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="StackO Test", size=(400,400))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.control.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnPress)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnPress(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 13:
            self.control.WriteText('\n>>>')
        else:
            event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    TestRun(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The `event.Skip()` line is crucial; during my research into this, I learned that a `KeyEvent` is usually followed by a `CharEvent`. The `CharEvent` is the part where the character is written to the `TextCtrl`. When you intercept the `KeyEvent`, the `CharEvent` is only called if you do so explicitly - `event.skip()` is therefore vital if you want your `TextCtrl` to otherwise behave as normal. Without it, any keyboard input not equal to ASCII keycode 13 would do nothing.

From my tests, it appears that there is something about declaring the `TextCtrl` to have style `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` that makes it print a newline after each call to `WriteText()`. My way gets around this though you will have more work to do with regard to making sure the insertion point is always in the right place, etc.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yea figured this out after a little tinkering, but great answer.

Comment: Maybe my particular setup/case isn't exactly the same but I prevented my `wx.TextCtrl.write(text)` from adding newlines by simply doing `wx.TextCtrl.write(text.rstrip())`, I was surprised this worked since I did not input any newlines into my `text` variable myself, but apparently they where somehow added by `.write()` and using `.rstrip()` on my textvariable stops it from doing that. (+1 for @chucksmash clear and extensive answer though).